# asp.net mvc c# create and display custom variable concatenate items from database table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-database-first

Lived in a hole after years in complex classic asp world - trying to get out ...
I'm not even sure how to search properly since the syntax have changed so much, but here is my attempt at explaining my problem in classic lingo:

- Existing Database / Database First

I want to display a concatenated variable on a details page.  For example a simple concatenation of the database results for first name, last name, suffix etc. column fields.
I cannot figure out how to create a concatenated string in a ViewModel, in the controller, in the View itself, metadata (via partialClasses), and then how to call and display it in the view.  Where is the best place to create this "variable" ?

ps. Guidance in which search terms to use / tutorials will be appreciated as well.

Comment: `myModel.Value = string.Format({0} {1}, FirstName, LastName)`

Answer (score 0):

the model is the right place for this not the controller or the view.

in your model something like

```
     public string ConcatenatedName
            {
                get
                {
                    return string.format("{0} {1} {2}",FirstName, LastName, Suffix) 
                }
            }

 public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set { _firstName = value;}
        }


 public string LastName
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set { _lastName = value;}
        }


 public string Suffix
        {
            get { return _suffix; }
            set { _suffix = value;}
        }
```

then use concatenated name in your view. Having it in the model allows you to check it in  unit tests which you will not be able to easily do in a view and the controller should not be cluttered with this and is just not the right place for it

**EDIT**: Assumption - I have made an assumption that you have separated the database and UI and are not using your db obj as your model for the views. I am assuming you have atleast put a middle layer in and are atleast mapping (eg automapper) from database object to viewmodel object

Comment: Since the model will be overwritten when database changes are made I created a MetaData class (also for validation / formatting) which are called from PartialClasses.cs.  
In the view however, using  
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ConcatenatedName)  
results in "'Example.Models.CUSTOMERS' does not contain definition for 'ConcatenatedName'"  ...
How would I call ConcatenatedName from the View?

Comment: could you post some of your code here? or link to it somewhere?